# Match number inside brackets in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a text that could possibly include words, numbers etc. All I want is to match the numbers inside brackets, but withtout matching them like this:

> Lorem 43 ipsum dolor 1 sit amet (355) some
>   other text.

I want to match the number 355, but since there are numbers without brackets, I get to this:

```
\(\b\d+\b\) - 1st variant
\(.+?\)     - 2nd variant
```

Presumably I get (355), but my php script is already under heavy load, matching to remove the brackets is not a an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match like your 1st variant, but capture only the digits in a group, like this

```
\((\d+)\)
```

And I think PHP supports named capture groups, so you could name it, so you aren't looking it up by index, like this I think

```
preg_match('/\((?<MatchedNumber>\d+)\)/', $searchText, $groups);
print_r($groups['MatchedNumber']);
```

Comment: @Anonymous, don't check `$groups[0]`, it's in `$groups[1]` or `$groups['MatchedNumber']`  see my edit (assuming my syntax is correct)

Comment: Thanks i forgot that preg_match returns array. Thanks once again. You saved me.

Comment: You probably don't need the `\b` since you are matching both sides explicitly.

Comment: @Douglas Leeder, correct, they aren't needed, I had just copied Anonymous' regex.  Removed them now though

Answer (score 3):

If you like you can remove the `\b`'s in the first one; they don't hurt anything but they're redundant. To capture the number and exclude the parentheses, use unescaped parentheses around the digits:

```
\((\d+)\)
```

This will capture the digits for later use. For example:

```
preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/', $sentence, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: What i want is to match the numbers without the brackets: i.e. (355) -> 355.

Comment: @Anonymous that's exactly what this does

Comment: Yeah i forgot preg_match returns array